# react-spring Animating a switch case

Tags: reactjs, animation, switch-statement, transition, react-spring

Been busting my head against this for a week now. I'm using [react-spring](https://github.com/drcmda/react-spring) to create a transition animation between pages. Those pages are defined by a switch case that is called within the render of a React Component.

I made a quick oversimplifeid sandbox with the odd behaviour:

https://codesandbox.io/s/50y5kkljz4

Most of this code is a simulation of my more complex stack.
Looking for any suggestions and what i'm missing.

**Is this a bug from react-spring?**

**Am I doing something that a no no in React?**

**Is it even possible to animate between (switch) cases?**

Things to try:

1. [Line 71] Comment out keys from the Transition Component. See what result.
2. [Line 74] Comment out the leave prop from the Transition Component. See result.

[Full API reference for react-spring](https://github.com/drcmda/react-spring/blob/master/API.md)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a subtle adjustment. You're passing to `<Transition>` a function in the form:

```
function(styles) {
  return <div styles={styles}>getComponent(...)</div>;
}
```

You're deferring resolving *what exact component* that is until the function is evaluated.

As `<Transition>` re-renders, the previous function, and the current function, will both evaluate to the same component, given by the current `index`, and you see this effect.

Instead, what you can do is:

```
    <Transition
      keys={this.state.index}
      from={{ opacity: 0 }}
      enter={{ opacity: 1 }}
      leave={{ opacity: 0 }}
    >
      {wrap(this.selectContent(type))}
    </Transition>
```

where:

```
const wrap = cmp => styles => <div style={styles}>{cmp}</div>
```

i.e. given an *actual component*, return a function that takes the `react-spring` styles and places them on a wrapper div.

I hope this helps!